# filtering objects based on their parameters, not values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have json objects that are shown on the page with ng-repeat. I can search through them but I need to be able to 'filter' them by a certain parameter with select html element as well.

To understand better, lets say this is my html code:

```
<select ng-model="selectedGroupToShow" ng-options="group.Name for group in myGroups">
    <option value="">-- choose something --</option>
</select>
```

Lets say myGroups Name attributes are "Group1, Group2, Group3 … ". They also have indeces and other parameters, but Name is what I am selecting from (this is what the user wants to see)

Objects are built like this:

```
{'groupID': value, 'parameter2':value, 'parameter3':value, …}
…
```

Now If I use selectedGroupToShow as a filter the objects are filtered by group.Name which is of course correct, but my objects do not have group.Name as a value in them. What they have is group ID number which is given as a value in parameter groupID.

Can I select through *groupID* values only somehow? I still need to show group.Name in select, but search for group.Id as a value in parameter 'groupID'?

Once again the problems I am facing are:

- filters search through all objects' values. I need to search only in one exact parameter for a certain value)
- for searching you usually use input field(what I am doing also) but I need to be able to use select for some parameters as well (the issue here is to select from objects' names, but to search from objects' id's for instance)

If I was unclear please don't hesitate to ask for more info (I had a hard time converting my problem into understandable question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a little bit of a hard time understanding the question 100%, I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="g.groupID as g.Name for g in groups"></select>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4709/

This should select the ID's for you, but label them as the Name for the user when he makes the selection.

The table "ngOptions" is a good reference for how to work with collections/arrays as options for a select element. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

**Edit:** New JSFiddle, filtering the list of groups by the specified parameter. http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4713/

Docs on filter: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

**Edit #2:** Users fiddle, configured to correctly filter. http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4722/

Comment: You understood my second problem perfectly; this works, thank you. My first and more important remains though: how to search for this id now  in a certain object parameter? I don't want the filter applied to all values of every parameter. Just for one exact parameter. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I think I get what you mean. See the new JSFiddle.

Comment: yes, you understood correctly, but the problem is I have to filter different array then groups array. So there are two arrays and one has groupID and the other has only ID. See updated fiddle (it doesnt work here, but it works in my code - only when I try to show ALL objects again it will only show those which dont have group id assigned): http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4720/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4721/ here a bit easier to see: this is what gets filtered (See text next to select box)

Comment: Where did you tell angular to filter by GroupId parameter only?

Comment: My bad-i thought that selectedGroupToShow is a instance of group but is instead just a new object to which you assign GroupId. If you have time you can try answering this as well since its related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830521/clear-filter-with-select-option-element 
thank you