# clearing filter in angularJS using select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I use the ngOptions directive in the HTML given below:

```
<select ng-model="selectedGroupToShow.Id" ng-options="g.Id as g.Name for g in myGroups">
    <option value>-- All --</option>
</select>
```

The filter I am using in ng-repeat to show my data goes like this:

```
filter:{GroupId:selectedGroupToShow.Id}"
```

Even if I use

```
filter:selectedGroupToShow
```

the issue stays the same.Resetting the filter..

This works perfectly, but when I want to clear the filter (select default option - 'All') it will only show data that doesn't have *GroupId* parameter set at all.

How can I show ALL the data (clear the filter) when choosing default option element within select?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think I understand your problem and the issue you are facing is when dropdown selected to --ALL-- its value is null and not undefined.
So to reset it you have to set it for undefined.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items| filter:{itemId:selectedGroupToShow.Id||undefined}">
         {{item.itemId}}
</div>
```

Please refer the below fiddle I have created for your problem.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb_satchitanand/ebp5p/3/)

Comment: You understood correctly:) Unfortunately If I use || undefined as you've shown above I get an error. If I try to put bracers () around it stays null when All is selected. I use the second filter in my question -> ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchItemsText | filter:selectedGroupToShow || undefined". I probably use wrong structure for || ?

Comment: I just used your syntax with parameter:value and it worked, I'll just leave it so. Thank you!

Comment: still if you know how to accomplish the same thing with the filter I wrote in the first comment above I'd be glad to know how

Comment: I guess **item** is a json object you are using, if so then I'm afraid to say how will your filter:searchItemsText will work since on what basis should it filter the value. If you can create a fiddle for your problem with the exact object structure then we might be able to help you.

Comment: searchItemsText is not the issue, you can leave that one out (it works). I only had problems converting your answer to work with the second filter above

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way, **just with an empty String value.**

Hope it could help anyone.

JADE code:

```
select.form-control(ng-model="productType", ng-init="productType='free'")
        option(value="free") FREE
        option(value="interest") INTEREST
        option(value="hybrid") HYBRID
        option(value="") ALL

.col-sm-6.col-md-4.col-lg-3(ng-repeat="product in productList | filter:{ type :productType }") {{product.name}}
```